# redirecting http to https excluding query of server by ip address

Tags: iis, redirect

How can I redirect all http://www.example.com traffic to https://www.example.com but I don't want to redirect http://1.2.3.4 to https://www.example.com (given that 1.2.3.4 is the ip address of www.example.com). The following rule will redirect unfortunately both

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="^0$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part you're looking to modify is the `<match url="(.*)" />`, as that will decide what matched url (in this case, it's pretty much anything) is redirected to HTTPS.

The format is a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). You can test different regular expressions [here](https://regexr.com) (and other places but this is my favourite one). So, in this case, you want it to only redirect the domain name and not the IP address.

Seeing as you don't need a catch-all redirect expression, just one that handles a certain domain name `http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com`, you could probably get away with the `www\.example\.com` regex selector.

So try this:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(www\.example\.com)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="^0$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```